# Projective limits of compact groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra, topological-groups

Is the projective limit of an exact sequence of projective systems of compact (not necessarily Hausdorff) topological groups exact?

Is the projective limit of nonempty compact (not necessarily Hausdorff) spaces compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: just take any counterexample in ordinary groups, and give all the groups the indiscrete topology.  Explicitly, for instance, you could take the natural projective system formed by the short exact sequences $$0\to p^n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)\to 0$$ whose limit is $$0\to 0\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}_p\to 0$$ which is not exact.

For the second question, you can use a related example.  Let $G_n$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ with the topology where the open sets are unions of cosets of $p^n\mathbb{Z}$.  The identity maps make these into an inverse system, and each $G_n$ is compact.  However, the inverse limit is $\mathbb{Z}$ with the $p$-adic topology, which is not compact.

Comment: @Eic Wofsey What is the indiscrete topology ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo: The trivial topology, with no open sets besides the empty set and the whole space.

Comment: In the sense of Bourbaki, where "compactness" includes the Hausdorff property, has the OP question an affirmative answer ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo: Yes.  For the first question the key lemma is that if an element in some term of the inverse system can be lifted to any higher term of the system, then it can be lifted to the limit.  For the second question, it's basically just Tychonoff's theorem (the key point being that Hausdorffness guarantees the inverse limit is closed in the product).

Comment: Thanks. Concerning the exactness of the proj. lim. functor for modules, I remember a sufficient condition called "Mittag-Leffler". What you say is that this condition is fulfilled when dealing with compact modules, isn't it ?

Comment: @nguyenquangdo: No, the Mittag-Leffler condition is different, and an inverse system of compact groups need not be Mittag-Leffler.  Also, as far as I know the Mittag-Leffler condition is only sufficient for exactness for sequential systems, not arbitrary inverse systems.

Comment: Thanks for the precise informations.