# Projective Limits of Compact Groups: Exact or Not?

Tags: general-topology, homological-algebra, topological-groups, separation-axioms, limits-colimits

I am reading the following lemma from Washington's book "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields":

> [image: Exactness of projective limits for compact groups]

On the other hand, there is a counterexample, given by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814936/projective-limits-of-compact-groups). The comments below this answer indicate that for projective limits to be exact, one should add Hausdorff condition, whose necessity I don't really understand.

So now I get very confused because I have a counterexample and a proof, and I am not able to locate a potential flaw in the proof, which does not assume (at least explicitly) Hausdorff-ness.

I would appreciate it very much if anyone can help me understand the subtle issue here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably in the book you quote, "compact groups" are assumed to be Hausdorff (either because this is part of their definition of a topological group or because it is part of their definition of "compact").  The Hausdorff assumption is used when they conclude that $\phi_{i,i-1}^B(b_i)=b_{i-1}$ by continuity.  All continuity gives you is that $\phi^B_{i,i-1}(b_i)$ is *a* limit of $(b_{i-1}^{(N)})$ (with respect to a subnet of the sequence along which $(b^{(N)})$ converges to $b$).  The Hausdorff assumption then tells you that $b_{i-1}$ is the *only* such limit (since limits are unique in Hausdorff spaces), and so $\phi_{i,i-1}^B(b_i)$ must be equal to $b_{i-1}$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for the great answer!